# do I always have to return a value even on error

Tags: go

If I have a function that looks like this

```
  func ThisIsMyComplexFunc() (ComplexStruct, error)
```

where ComplexStruct is a big struct that usually contain loads of values.

What if the function stumbles on an error right in the beginning, before I even started building my struct, ideally I would like to only return the error, e.g.

```
  return nil, err
```

but it wont let me do it, it forces me to create a dummy complex struct and return that together with the error, even though I never want to use the struct.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Consider reading the ["Error handling and Go"](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function is declared to return two values, then you will need to return two values.

One option that might simplify your code is to use named return values:

```
func ThisIsMyComplexFunc() (s ComplexStruct, err error) {
    ...
}
```

Now you can just assign to `s` and/or `err` and then use a bare `return` statement.  You will still be returning a `ComplexStruct` value, but you don't need to initialise it manually (it will default to a zero value).

Answer (score 2):

You can return a pointer to the struct:

```
func ThisIsMyComplexFunc() (*ComplexStruct, error) {
  ...
  if somethingIsWrong {
    return nil, err
  }
  ...
  return &theStructIBuilt, nil
}
```

In general, it'll be cheaper to pass big structs by pointer anyway, because it's easier to copy a pointer than the whole struct.